# Минимальное значение числа в input type text

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="text" name="summakr" required id="inpt" placeholder="0.1000">
```

Нужен конкретно type text но значение min не применяется к этому типу

Как поступить что бы установить минимальное введенное значение в 0.016, не меняя type на number?

Comment: А почему вы в верстке используете type = text у input для числовых значений, вместо number?

Comment: Дизайн на number слетает для инпута

Comment: Yanulya 2, используйте [этот урок для редизайна input](https://snipp.ru/html-css/input-type-number?ysclid=l33ihiswm1). Вы конечно же можете ограчить ввод в input text буквы, а вводить только цифры, однако зачем Вам городить огород кодом JS, но все же- функциональнее получится с input type number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если прям никак нельзя использовать `type="number"`, то вот вариант:

Устанавливаете минимальное значение через `data-min`, так же как в `min`.
Если `value` < `min`, то в `value` ставится `min`.

```js
document.querySelector('#inpt').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  let target = e.target;
  if(isNumber(target.value)) {
    target.setCustomValidity('');
    let min = Number(target.getAttribute('data-min'));
    let val = Number(target.value);
    if(val < min) target.value = min;
  } else target.setCustomValidity('Only number');
});

function isNumber(n) {
   return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

```css
input:invalid {border-color: red;}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inpt" placeholder="0.1000" data-min="0">
```

Или вариант, когда `value` не заменяется, но инпут становится невалидным.

```js
document.querySelector('#inpt').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  let target = e.target;
  if(isNumber(target.value)) {
    target.setCustomValidity('');
    let min = Number(target.getAttribute('data-min'));
    let val = Number(target.value);
    if(val < min) target.setCustomValidity('min '+min);
  } else target.setCustomValidity('Only number');
});

function isNumber(n) {
   return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

```css
input:invalid {border-color: red;}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inpt" placeholder="0.1000" data-min="0">
```

Answer (score 2):

Лучше сделать с type="number", а дизайн можно на свое усмотрение подкорректировать